# Elasticsearch exception when index max size is exceeded

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm writing to Elasticsearch with node js, and I need to handle a case where the max index size is exceeded so that I can write to a new index if that happens. The problem is that I can't find the name of the exception or the status code for that case. Thanks.

Comment: But... you now the Max Index and the current index? Check them!

Answer (score 0):

Which limit are you referring to? Maximum number of documents per shard (not per index), which is 2^31?

Anyway, the best approach to switch to a new index is the rollover index API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/indices-rollover-index.html

There's no need to code something together yourself.

Comment: You may need to upgrade your version of elasticsearch to use rollover indexes. That is a feature first introduced in version 5.0

Comment: @xeraa I'm using ES version 2.3.4 not 5. Could you please give an example in code? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-time-based-indices-efficiently is a great starting point, but you will need 5.x. Rather than build anything yourself I'd invest the time to upgrade your cluster.